# JAVAFX Making A List Of Tree Views

Tags: treeview, javafx-2

I am working on a JavaFx Application in which I need a list of Tree Views.
This is an application solving problem , every time I create a new problem a new tree view is created.

I want to maintain a list of such tree views which is feasible to scroll.

What I tried?

1.)Create a scroll pane and put a vbox in it.
2.)Add tree views in a vbox.

Issues with this

When I resize the window the vbox does not resize.(While putting any container inside scroll pane I cannot set Fit To Parent From Scene Builder)

Please suggest a good way to implement list of tree views

MyCode

```
@FXML
private VBox treeContainer;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    for(int j=0;j<3;++j){
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Item " + j);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        String[] names = {"SubItem1","SubItem2", "SubItem3","SubItem4", "SubItem5","SubItem6","SubItem7",};
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> (names[i]);            
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }        
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String> (rootItem);
        tree.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        tree.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");

        treeContainer.getChildren().add(tree);
    }


}
```

Comment: Solved by using one tree view , making root (not visible) and adding children every time

Answer (score 0):

> "Issues with this
>
> When I resize the window the vbox does not resize. ..."

Use "fit to" properties of ScrollPane.

```
<ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" ... >
</ScrollPane>
```